# File variable gets mysteriously emptied after certain unrelated code in Android Java

Tags: java, android

Okay, so in my Android Studio project, I have a file path that leads to a .jpg file in my app's cache, captured with a share image intent, from Google Photos in this case (though others like share from Chrome achieve following result).

I pass it into an AsyncTask as a String in an array using `.getAbsolutePath()`.

When I do `System.out.println(new File(data[0]).length());`, `data[0]` being my absolute image file path, I get this output: `1657139`.

However, for some reason, the file gets emptied somewhere along my code, and returns `0` for `.length()` and `false` for `.canRead()`. I cannot pinpoint the exact location that it occurs, because it seems like every time the position where it empties changes. (I setup print statements everywhere to check).

...actually, now testing it a few more times, it seems to mainly be empting after these two lines of code, from Algorithmia:

```
System.out.println(localFile2.length());
System.out.println(localFile2.canRead());
System.out.println("reading");
//below lines
DataDirectory AlgoOutputDirectory = algorithmiaClient.dir("data://.algo/deeplearning/ColorfulImageColorization/temp");
DataDirectory ChromoPhotoDataDirectory = algorithmiaClient.dir("data://TrivisionZero/ChromoPhotoData");
//above lines
System.out.println(localFile2.length());
System.out.println(localFile2.canRead());
```

As the output for that is:

```
02-15 22:22:36.373 8380-8415/? I/System.out: 77647 //correct size
02-15 22:22:36.373 8380-8415/? I/System.out: true
02-15 22:22:36.373 8380-8415/? I/System.out: reading
//here's the algorithmia code
02-15 22:22:36.388 8380-8415/? I/System.out: 0 //now it's empty
02-15 22:22:36.388 8380-8415/? I/System.out: false
02-15 22:22:36.388 8380-8415/? I/System.out: reading
```

I realize this isn't a site specifically for Algorithmia issues, but their response time is quite longer than ideal. So if anybody has ANY idea why the size is going down to `0` all of a sudden, it be really appreciated. Thanks.

Extra information: the same photo picked from Google Photos or local storage using the image picking window instead of the share option seems to always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I feel genuinely stupid for posting this now, and especially because I figured out the solution moments after!

So I have this code, which clears the unneeded app cache on start, right? I sort of forgot about that, so it was always running on start. Well, it was actually deleting the file I was referencing, seemingly at the exact same time, so I thought it might be the specific code it was going blank at. Nope! Just my forgetful self letting code I wrote delete a file I needed. :P

I commented this code, and boom, it works 100% of the time now.

I'm just leaving this here in the small case that one unique individual has the exact same issue (what's the chances of that?)

Ugh.

Comment: Made me smile! One we have all done, but never admit to!